# Delete last 30 days data using batch class not working

Tags: apex, batch, class

i have been trying to delete last 30 days records through batch class, i am not getting any errors. i don't see my records were not deleted while i run the batch job, please advice. thanks in advance..
Code:

```
global class BatchClaim implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
            DateTime s = System.Now().addDays(-30);
        return Database.getQueryLocator
            ([Select id,Name from Claim_Job where LastModifiedDate <= :s AND Process_Status_c__c = 'Completed']);

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Claim_Job>scope){
               delete scope;
    }
```

Comment: Before deleting `scope` please debug and check its value or size.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is incorrect: `Process_Status_c__c = 'Completed'`, it is probably `Process_Status__c = 'Completed'`.

`Claim_Job` is probably `Claim_Job__c`

You need to add:

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // execute any post-processing operations
    }
```

as well...

All methods should be part on an interface class. Try this:

```
global class BatchClaim implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
            DateTime s = System.Now().addDays(-30);
        return Database.getQueryLocator
            ([Select id,Name from Claim_Job__c where LastModifiedDate <= :s AND Process_Status__c = 'Completed']);

    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Claim_Job__c>scope){
               delete scope;
    }

   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
            // execute any post-processing operations
        } 
  }
```

You could use the **SystemModStamp** instade of **LastModifiedDate** but take a look to the differences between those two fields **[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/11/force-com-soql-performance-tips-systemmodstamp-vs-lastmodifieddate-2.html)**, there are some points to consider when using one or the other.

Comment: better to use `SystemModStamp` rather than `LastModifiedDate` since that is indexed.

Comment: Yes, if you want to track system modifications and track them in your DateTime, yes.. it would be better. That way you can track changes done no only by user but by system operations like triggers for example. Good point.